# Change storage mode of MTKView's depth texture

Tags: metal, mtkview

In the Metal's profiler I get this suggestion:

```
"Texture:0x12880c010 "MTKView Depth"" has storage mode 'Private' but was a transient render target accessed exclusively by the GPU

Consider changing the storage mode to 'Memoryless'.
```

This texture is created by MTKView automatically if `depthStencilPixelFormat` property is set to a meaningful value. It is even possible to control the texture usage by setting `depthStencilAttachmentTextureUsage` property.

But I can't see how can I change the storage mode of this texture.
It seems that the MTKView should somehow set the right storage mode automatically as this excerpt from the documentation suggests:

```
...the view automatically creates those textures for you 
and configures them as part of any render passes that the view creates.
```

But in my case it certainly fails to take into account that in my pipeline I don't read from this texture.

So the question is how can I change the storage mode of the depth texture of MTKView to .memoryless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MTKView** has a [property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview/3951238-depthstencilstoragemode?language=objc) called: `depthStencilStorageMode`, which has The default value is `MTLStorageModePrivate`.

```
_view.depthStencilStorageMode = MTLStorageModeMemoryless;
```